# Turn random bytes to .NET decimal 0..1 fractional range

Tags: c#, random

I'm playing with a TRNG usb device, and successfully turning the random bytes into various usable data in C#.

I'd like to create a .NET decimal value between 0..1 (ex: 0.37327) directly from the bytes using binary reader (or other direct bytes -> decimal) method.

`// assume: byte[] random_data of appropriate length, patterned for a 0..1 range
decimal value = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(random_data)).ReadDecimal();`

I was looking for the byte format of decimal, but it looks like it may not be a standard?

- [How do I convert byte values into decimals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467893/how-do-i-convert-byte-values-into-decimals)
- [.NET decimal cross-platform standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28080097/net-decimal-cross-platform-standard)

This is for hobby work, so it's acceptable to me to use something that might change in future.
I've looked at the bytes generated for sample input decimal values - I see negative and precision flags (1Ch max in last int32?), but the min/max data values dumping compiler constants are stumping me a bit, and I'm generate above zero values or invalid values:

- fractional value nearest 1 (.99...9): FFFFFF0F 6102253E 5ECE4F20 00001C00
- fractional value nearest 0 (.00...1): 01000000 00000000 00000000 00001C00

Can you help me onto the correct path for generating a full fractional 0..1 range?

**Edit with "final" code, thanks to everyone!**

Here's the C# code I ended up with to create an unbiased random decimal of range [0..1] from a suitable random byte stream (like a TRNG device, www.Random.org, or CSPRNG algorithm). Generated values look good to the eyeball, boundary tests pass, and as long as I avoided embarassing typos and copy/paste bugs, this should be usable as-is.

Thanks for the help and interesting discussions!

```
private decimal RandomDecimalRange01()
{
    // 96 bits of random data; we'll use 94 bits to directly map decimal's max precision 0..1 range
    byte[] data = new byte[12];
    decimal value = 0;

    // loop until valid value is generated, discarding invalids values. Mostly controlled by top 2 bits: 11 is always invalid, 00 or 01, is always valid, 10 has valid and invalid ranges. Odds make loop generally find value in one or a few iterations.
    while (true)
    {
        // Acquire random bytes from random source (like TRNG device or CSPRNG api)
        if (!trng.GetBytes(data))
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to aquire random bytes from source");
        }
        else
        {
            // Read 94 random bits (pull 96 bits, discard 2)
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(data));
            int low = reader.ReadInt32();
            int mid = reader.ReadInt32();
            int high = reader.ReadInt32() & 0x3FFFFFFF; // don't consume upper 2 random bits - out of range

            // Discard invalid values and reloop (interpret special invalid value as 1)
            if (high > 542101086)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if (high == 542101086)
            {
                if (mid > 1042612833)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else if (mid == 1042612833)
                {
                    if (low > 268435455)
                    {
                        // Special override to generate 1 value for inclusive [0..1] range - interpret the smallest invalid value as 1. Remove code for exclusive range [0..1)
                        if (low == 268435456)
                        {
                            value = 1m; // return 1.0
                            break;
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }

            // return random decimal created from parts - positive, maximum precision 28 (1C) scale
            value = new decimal(low, mid, high, false, 28);
            break;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Sample generated values running TrueRNGPro TRNG device bytes through algorithm

```
0.8086691474438979082567747041
0.4268035919422123276460607186
0.7758625805098585303332549015
0.0701321080502462116399370731
0.3127190777525873850928167447
0.6022236739048965325585049764
0.1244605652187291191393036867
```

Tests around interesting boundary values

```
// test databyte values for max & min ranges
new byte[] { 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x61, 0x02, 0x25, 0x3E, 0x5E, 0xCE, 0x4F, 0x20 }; // boundary: 1 too large for algorithm, will be discarded
new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x61, 0x02, 0x25, 0x3E, 0x5E, 0xCE, 0x4F, 0x20 }; // boundary: special 1 more than largest valid .99999..., interpret as 1 value
new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x0F, 0x61, 0x02, 0x25, 0x3E, 0x5E, 0xCE, 0x4F, 0x20 }; // boundary: largest valid value .9999...
new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }; // boundary: smallest valid value, should be 0
new byte[] { 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }; // boundary: 1 more than smallest valid value, should be .000...1
```

Comment: ReadUInt64() / Math.Pow(2, 64).  Use BigInteger if you want to swallow more bytes, hard to imagine that is necessary.

Comment: That's what I started with, and it's certainly a pragmatic answer. But in theory (I haven't measured) a divide is slower than a direct load, and there are lots more states available in a 96 bit decimal than a 64 bit int.

Comment: Right, that is only a theory.  It has hardware support from the processor, the Decimal type does not and is all done in software.  Measure.

Comment: I ran some tests; binary load to decimal is about twice as fast as ReadUInt64()/(decimal)ulong.MaxValue. Not too big a surprise since software divide, as you say. I also tried IEEE double and float divides; double was about the same as decimal divide, barely faster. Float was much closer to raw binary load. But I don't know what bias if any I'm introducing via the IEEE types. So I still need to squeeze unbiased value limiting into the raw binary read, but can double the time taken and still be better than the safe decimal divide, plus have more bits of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits(v=vs.110).aspx

> The binary representation of a Decimal number consists of a 1-bit
>   sign, a 96-bit integer number, and a scaling factor used to divide the
>   integer number and specify what portion of it is a decimal fraction.
>   The scaling factor is implicitly the number 10, raised to an exponent
>   ranging from 0 to 28.
>
> The return value is a four-element array of 32-bit signed integers.
>
> The first, second, and third elements of the returned array contain
>   the low, middle, and high 32 bits of the 96-bit integer number.
>
> The fourth element of the returned array contains the scale factor and
>   sign. It consists of the following parts:
>
> Bits 0 to 15, the lower word, are unused and must be zero.
>
> Bits 16 to 23 must contain an exponent between 0 and 28, which
>   indicates the power of 10 to divide the integer number.
>
> Bits 24 to 30 are unused and must be zero.
>
> Bit 31 contains the sign: 0 mean positive, and 1 means negative.

You are looking for 0 <= 96bitinteger / 10<sup>exponent</sup> <= 1

Multiplying through, this is the same as 0 <= 96bitinteger <= 10^exponent

This would enumerate every possibile pair of 96bitinteger and exponent that would produce a `decimal` value between 0 and 1 (assuming the sign bit is set to 0).

```
for (int exponent=0; exponent<=28; exponent++) {
    BigInteger max = BigInteger.Pow(10, exponent);
    for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
        var fmt = "96bitinteger: {0}, exponent: {1}";
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format(fmt, i, exponent));
    }
}
```

### Using exponent=28

10<sup>28</sup> in hex is `204fce5e 3e250261 10000000`. So once you place the 32-bit numbers according to the docs, and then create  fhe final 32-bits accounting for the fact *for some reason when they say bit 0 they mean the highest order bit*, it isn't too hard to construct the decimal number 1 from bytes.

```
int[] data = new int[] { 0x10000000, 0x3e250261, 0x204fce5e, 0x1C0000 };
var random_data = data.SelectMany(BitConverter.GetBytes).ToArray();
decimal value = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(random_data)).ReadDecimal();
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Consider the more general `new int[] { a, b, c, 0x1C0000 }`. The constraints on a b and c, for creating a decimal number 0 <= d <= 1 are

```
if c < 0x204fce5e:
    a can be anything
    b can be anything
elif c = 0x204fce5e:
    if b < 0x3e250261:
        a can be anything
    elif b = 0x3e250261
        constrain a <= 10000000
    b can not be greater than 0x3e250261
c can not be greater than 0x204fce5e.
```

Comment: Thanks for the link! So probably my problem is that 2^96 != 10^28, and if I just randomly fill the the first three data integers my max is really 2^96 / 10^28 ~= 7.92? I'll have to limit out the numbers >= 1 in an unbiased way.

Comment: @JoelMc I've added some more specifics.

Comment: That makes sense. I got that working and appears to be generating good looking numbers and react approprately at the boundaries. I snipped off the leading high bytes in hi/c since they are always out of bounds. That leaves the high 2 useful bytes with 2 good states (00 or 01) always acceptable, 1 bad state (11) always too large, and 1 (10) that depends on other values. Doing the discard-and-try-again method to retain distribution randomness, that gives me between .5 & .75 chance to pull a valid value.

Comment: One question left - from above comments, I noticed my current actual range is 0 to .999... I think it's safe to take one invalid value and make it 1 to get the full 0...1 range - any opinion on that? I don't see a problem as long as I only pick one value and not a whole class - then 1 will be equally likely as any other value.

Comment: I won't think any less of you as a person. Worst case scenario is that you end up with something like this https://xkcd.com/221/ .

Answer (score 0):

- Do you want uniform distribution between 0 and 1 (including both ends)?
- Do the original data is also uniform at the byte level?
- How much precision do you really need?
- Do you need decimal or float/double would do?

If you use decimal, I don't think you would get uniform distribution as you cannot use whole range of all bytes.

With floating points, I think it might be easier to do bits manipulations if you create a number between 1 and 2 and then subtract 1. However, you would never get exactly 1.0.

Comment: * Yes I would like uniform distribution
* Yes, the input byte data is uniformly distributed
* This is hobby/self-improvement work learning more about good conversion of TRNG to useful data, so I don't need perfection or high precision per se, just trying to learn what I can to do it right
* Floats and Doubles are on my list, too. But the IEEE format is well documented, so I tackled decimal first

Comment: You may be right that I can't get uniform distribution, but that same problem is solvable in integer ranges (like pulling a 6 dice value from 4 bits), so I imagine there's a "right way" that can preserve distribution with decimals.

That's a cool trick between 1 & 2 - 1. Come to think of it, my current methods isn't generating 1 either, just 0 to .999...

Comment: Well, usually, you won't care about the difference between 0.999... and 1. Or if you care, then you should probably works at a given precision (say 3 digits) in which case, you would simply extend by one "step" the range. In decimal, you might select the "precision" first, generate the number and normalize the result (not sure if necessary). With floating points, if you don't include 2, then you would generate a number between 1 and 2 and get the normalization for free by subtracting 1.